# Find a css class inside a link

Tags: jquery

I want to replace a class inside a link element with jQuery.

For example, in the following code, On clicking the link `.myclass`, I want to change the `icon1` with `icon2`:

```
<a class="myclass" href="#"><i class="icon icon1"></i></a>
```

I do not know how can I find and reach to the class icon1.
I'm trying this and does not work:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
    $(this).html().removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');    
 });
```

Comment: Remove the `html()`, this gets the HTML source, and you're calling the `{add,remove}Class` on that (a string), and not the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/exvS8/1/)**

Use this,

```
$('.myclass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('i',this).removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');   

     //or

    $('.icon1',this).removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');
});
```

or **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

```
$('.myclass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('.icon1').removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');    
});
```

**Note :**

The next time you click the link, `$('.icon1')` wont work. So try using `$('i')` or `$('.icon')`

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('.myclass').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.icon1').removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');    
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

There should be

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.icon1').removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');    
 });
```

You have to refer to the element that the class you are changing.

Answer (score 2):

Since `.icon1` is a child element to the current element, you have to use `.find()`/`.children()` on the current element to find it.

Try,

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.icon1').removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

look here: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qokayaye/1/edit)

```
$('.myclass').click(function(){
        $(this).children().removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');    
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myclass').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon1').addClass('icon2');   
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nazmoonnoor/exvS8/2/)